# Trouble connecting to remote printer with cups

Tags: printing

I am running two Ubuntu servers at two different physical locations, server-A runs Lubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, and server-B runs Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 LTS. I would like a user on server-A to be able to print to a printer connected to server-B. This used to work when server-B was running a very old (unsupported) version of Ubuntu from 2008 by configuring the URI on the CUPS server on server-A with 'ipp://server-B/printers/MinoltaPS' where MinoltaPS is the name of the printer on server-B. Since replacing the old server-B with a new machine and Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 LTS, that URI no longer works. I get an error message on server-A, stating it cannot connect to that printer. I tried turning off the firewall on server-A and server-B, but this did not help.

Does anyone know what to put in the URI on server-A?

Thanks, Gary

Comment: Did you share the printer on server-b?

Answer (score 0):

On `server-B`, access the CUPS admin page (`http://localhost:631/admin`) and ensure that BOTH the <kbd>Share printers connected to this system</kbd> and <kbd>Allow printing from the Internet</kbd> are checked.

Interesting info can be found in `/var/log/cups/`.